# Why can I not vote on Area51?

Tags: support, voting, area-51

I am new to Area51, but have 151 rep. How can I vote on questions and/or propose new questions for a site I am committed to? I see no up or down vote buttons, no "ask new question" button, and the vote numbers are not clickable when I mouseover. What am I missing?

Comment: see also- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54071/why-no-voting-for-on-topic-off-topic-during-commitment-phase-in-area-51

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't propose new questions or vote on existing questions for a site in the "commitment" phase.

What would be the point?

The site doesn't need any more example questions or any more questions marked as on or off topic - it has enough (otherwise it wouldn't be in the commitment phase).

The next point at which you can ask questions is when it goes into beta - but these should be **real** questions.

Comment: You assume that a topic that is in then commitment phase has enough questions. That is subjective. I have seen sites where it clearly wasn't clear enough (e.g. the name and the description weren't well matched).

Comment: @cdiggins - while the site *may* in reality need more example questions to properly define it, the fact that it's in the commitment phase means that it has enough as laid down by the rules.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. My quibble is with the rules. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The system is broken. You should be able to. The system gives a disproportionate amount of weight and influence to early contributors.