# How do I use Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

I just committed to an Area 51 proposal and I am unable to do anything except view example questions. I have 51 reputation points so I am supposed to be able to comment and vote, but there is nothing on the page I can click on except Link and Flag. Not only that, the Contact email address area51@stackexchange.com bounces. Can someone please explain this brokenness?

Comment: Which proposal?

Comment: Role-Playing Games, which is in Commitment as you correctly guessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposal you committed to is probably in the Commit stage, so [all of the functionality in the Define tab has been frozen.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54071/why-no-voting-for-on-topic-off-topic-during-commitment-phase-in-area-51)

Don't know about the email addy.

Comment: It is indeed in the Commitment state. Thank you for explaining this. It is a bit frustrating trying to use a site which has "gone dark" as pointed out in your link.

Answer (score 1):

The email address is actually area51@**stackoverflow**.com (because the company is Stack Overflow, Inc).  It's a bit confusing, so we'll try to get area51@stackexchange.com going to the same place.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the email link has been fixed.