# Can't comment or ask questions in commitment phase!

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why no voting for on-topic/off-topic during commitment phase in Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54071/why-no-voting-for-on-topic-off-topic-during-commitment-phase-in-area-51)

I'm committed to the philosophy SE now and my reputation is 71 (just because 4 people referred to me). But I still can't vote up, make comments or even ask questions! Any ideas what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users are not allowed to vote, comment and ask questions in the commitment phase. This status is by-design. See the following meta question and answers for more info:

[Why no voting for on-topic/off-topic during commitment phase in Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54071/why-no-voting-for-on-topic-off-topic-during-commitment-phase-in-area-51)