# Why I can't post questions on StackExchange Area51?

Tags: support, questions, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can I not vote on Area51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53974/why-can-i-not-vote-on-area51)

I committed to three projects and I have reputation 151 on Area51. Why can't I post some questions to projects I committed to?

Thank you!

Comment: See also - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53974/why-can-i-not-vote-on-area51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by the time you can commit, the "post question" phase (called "definition") is already over. You'll have to wait until the site goes into beta. But then you can post *real* questions, not just example ones.

Comment: answer stealing pony avatar creator person...

Comment: what it is supposed to mean?

Comment: @MartyIX - Jaun was just having a joke with balpha.  Jaun was going to write the same answer but balpha beat him to it.  The 'pony avatar' bit is in reference to the unicorn avatars that balpha created (see his profile page for links) ; )

Comment: Actually, @Juan (or "Downvoter", as the elders used to call him) was 10 seconds faster. His answer, however, lacked the poetic beauty that is inherent to mine.